# reading in datetime from csv evokes "unconverted data remains: 0" TypeError

Tags: datetime, pandas, strptime

I am trying to index a datetime that is being formed from 3 columns representing (year, dayofyear, and 2400hr time).

```
2014,323,1203,47.77,320.9
2014,323,1204,48.46,402.6
2014,323,1205,49.2,422.7
2014,323,1206,49.82,432.4
2014,323,1207,50.03,438.6
2014,323,1208,50.15,445.4
2014,323,1209,50.85,449.7
2014,323,1210,50.85,454.4
2014,323,1211,50.85,458.1
2014,323,1212,50.91,460.2
```

I am using the following code:

```
In [1]:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [2]:

def parse(yr, yearday, hrmn):
          date_string = ' '.join([yr, yearday, hrmn])
          print(date_string)
          return datetime.strptime(date_string,"%Y %j %H%M")
In [3]:


df = pd.read_csv('home_prepped.dat', parse_dates={'datetime':[0,1,2]},
                  date_parser=parse, index_col='datetime', header=None)
```

I have had success bringing it in when the data was flawed (had extra data over DST change), and now that it is fixed (removed and stitched back together) I am having this error (in its entirety):

```
2014 92 2355
2014 92 2356
2014 92 2357
2014 92 2358
2014 92 2359
2014 92 2400
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-9c710834ee23> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 df = pd.read_csv('home_prepped.dat', parse_dates={'datetime':[0,1,2]}, date_parser=parse, index_col='datetime', header=None)

/Volumes/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, dialect, compression, doublequote, escapechar, quotechar, quoting, skipinitialspace, lineterminator, header, index_col, names, prefix, skiprows, skipfooter, skip_footer, na_values, na_fvalues, true_values, false_values, delimiter, converters, dtype, usecols, engine, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, na_filter, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, warn_bad_lines, error_bad_lines, keep_default_na, thousands, comment, decimal, parse_dates, keep_date_col, dayfirst, date_parser, memory_map, float_precision, nrows, iterator, chunksize, verbose, encoding, squeeze, mangle_dupe_cols, tupleize_cols, infer_datetime_format, skip_blank_lines)
    463                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    464 
--> 465         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    466 
    467     parser_f.__name__ = name

/Volumes/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    249         return parser
    250 
--> 251     return parser.read()
    252 
    253 _parser_defaults = {

/Volumes/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in read(self, nrows)
    708                 raise ValueError('skip_footer not supported for iteration')
    709 
--> 710         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
    711 
    712         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

/Volumes/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in read(self, nrows)
   1209             data = dict((k, v) for k, (i, v) in zip(names, data))
   1210 
-> 1211             names, data = self._do_date_conversions(names, data)
   1212             index, names = self._make_index(data, alldata, names)
   1213 

/Volumes/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _do_date_conversions(self, names, data)
   1033             data, names = _process_date_conversion(
   1034                 data, self._date_conv, self.parse_dates, self.index_col,
-> 1035                 self.index_names, names, keep_date_col=self.keep_date_col)
   1036 
   1037         return names, data

/Volumes/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _process_date_conversion(data_dict, converter, parse_spec, index_col, index_names, columns, keep_date_col)
   2100 
   2101             _, col, old_names = _try_convert_dates(converter, colspec,
-> 2102                                                    data_dict, orig_names)
   2103 
   2104             new_data[new_name] = col

/Volumes/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _try_convert_dates(parser, colspec, data_dict, columns)
   2132     to_parse = [data_dict[c] for c in colnames if c in data_dict]
   2133 
-> 2134     new_col = parser(*to_parse)
   2135     return new_name, new_col, colnames
   2136 

/Volumes/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in converter(*date_cols)
   2048                                                dayfirst=dayfirst)
   2049                 except Exception:
-> 2050                     return generic_parser(date_parser, *date_cols)
   2051 
   2052     return converter

/Volumes/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/date_converters.pyc in generic_parser(parse_func, *cols)
     36     for i in range(N):
     37         args = [c[i] for c in cols]
---> 38         results[i] = parse_func(*args)
     39 
     40     return results

<ipython-input-2-57e18ddd7deb> in parse(yr, yearday, hrmn)
      1 def parse(yr, yearday, hrmn):
      2           date_string = ' '.join([yr, yearday, hrmn])
----> 3           return datetime.strptime(date_string,"%Y %j %H%M")

/Volumes/anaconda/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/_strptime.pyc in _strptime(data_string, format)
    326     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    327         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
--> 328                           data_string[found.end():])
    329 
    330     year = None

ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0
```

I am looking for suggestions as to how to debug or work around this. I have gone through the data and according to what I have read in similar posts I should be looking for extraneous time data, which is not there.

Thanks.

Comment: Add `print(date_string)` to your `parser` function before the `return`.  Then rerun your code and see what the troublesome string looks like.

Comment: ok, I reran it and it returns the parsed datetime string quite nicely; i am stumped! It returns the first days worth of values... 2014 92 1931
2014 92 1932
2014 92 1933
2014 92 1934
2014 92 1935

Comment: .. so you're saying that now there *is* no error?

Comment: haha, sorry if I was unclear. There is still an error and I still don't understand why as I did not notice any flaws in the date_string. I'll update the question to reflect the updated function and results. Is there a way I can upload the csv to you, as you suggested yesterday with that dpaste site? I could not use that site though, perhaps the data was too large? It's only 8mb, but took forever to paste into that link you gave me...

Comment: `24` isn't an acceptable input for `%H`-- as the docs explain, that only accepts from 00-23.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out DSM. I found this page on use of time.strptime, specifically looking at %R, but I think it may be deprecated? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm If not, I wonder how I could use it to work my format into a datetime string?